# Forcing a new line after an enumerated list

Tags: enumerate

I've got a bit of a silly problem. Here is a picture:

[image]

All I want is to have the "Of these two solutions to not have an indent, (I've got no idea why latex does this). I generally fix the problem by using `\\` to start a new line. Unfortunately I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item The first solution would be to find the solution to the first minimization problem mentioned in the subsection Situation 1 and then given the $\theta$ matrix calculated there, use that matrix for the minimization problem found in Subsection 2.
\item The second solution is to perform the two minimization problems concurrently. i.e perform the minimization for both $\theta$ and $X$. 
\end{enumerate}
\\
Of these two solutions, the solution mentioned in the second point is the most optimal one.
```

Seriously have a) No idea why is complaining and b) how to fix it. Anyone please help!

Comment: If you're using ``\\`` to end paragraph, stop doing it. A new paragraph is obtained by just leaving a blank line. If you don't want a new paragraph (with its indent) after an `enumerate`, just don't leave a blank line, as karlkoeller says.

Comment: You should almost never use `\\ ` except to end tabular rows. A blank line denotes end of paragraph, and you are using indented paragraphs, so if you do not want a new paragraph don't have a blank line.

Comment: And if you want a new paragraph but without the indent use `\noindent` at the beginning of the new paragraph. To remove the indent globally have a look at the `parskip` package

Comment: @Bordaigorl Use of `\noindent` in a document is usually a sign that something is wrong...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle agreed but it is still better than `\\ `! There are cases in my opinion where you can sacrifice uniformity to serve the content or a specific corner case...but this should be rare and well motivated indeed

Comment: @Bordaigorl but I can't even think of a corner case where after a list you'd want to add a blank line and `\noindent` rather than just not add a blank line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah no, I meant in general, not after a list. Certainly it is not good for this situation but it seemed to me the OP was using newlines elsewhere as well to emulate `\noindent`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply remove `\\` and leave no blank line after `enumerate`. When `enumerate` ends, it introduces itself a new non-indented paragraph.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first solution would be to find the solution to the first minimization problem mentioned in the subsection Situation 1 and then given the $\theta$ matrix calculated there, use that matrix for the minimization problem found in Subsection 2.
\item The second solution is to perform the two minimization problems concurrently. i.e perform the minimization for both $\theta$ and $X$.
\end{enumerate}
Of these two solutions, the solution mentioned in the second point is the most optimal one.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @user1638809 You're welcome